# ClientError: Annotation value 10 found in labels. This is greater than number of classes., exit code: 2

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

My total number of classes is 10

1-"Button_damage"
2-"Cracks"
3-"Edge_damage"
4-"Frame_damage"
5-"Hinge_damage"
6-"Screen_damage"
7-"Good_Button"
8-"Good_Hinge"
9-"Good_screen"
10-"Good_frame"

When I give num_classes=10 in hyperparameter it throws a error.

ClientError: Annotation value 10 found in labels. This is greater than number of classes., exit code: 2

I changed num_classes=9 and tried, it shows same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was worked when I changed the num_classes=11. Because it adds one label "0" by default.

0-"BACKGROUND"
1-"Button_damage"
2-"Cracks"
3-"Edge_damage"
4-"Frame_damage"
5-"Hinge_damage"
6-"Screen_damage"
7-"Good_Button"
8-"Good_Hinge"
9-"Good_screen"
10-"Good_frame"